# SQL Server DELETE is slower with indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-delete

I have an SQL Server 2005 database, and I tried putting indexes on the appropriate fields in order to speed up the `DELETE` of records from a table with millions of rows (`big_table` has only 3 columns), but now the `DELETE` execution time is even *longer*!  (1 hour versus 13 min for example)

I have a relationship between to tables, and the column that I filter my `DELETE` by is in the other table.  For example

```
DELETE FROM big_table
WHERE big_table.id_product IN (
SELECT small_table.id_product FROM small_table
WHERE small_table.id_category = 1)
```

Btw, I've also tried:

```
DELETE FROM big_table
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM small_table
WHERE small_table.id_product = big_table.id_product
AND small_table.id_category = 1)
```

and while it seems to run slightly faster than the first, it's still a lot slower with the indexes than without.

I created indexes on these fields:

1. `big_table.id_product`
2. `small_table.id_product`
3. `small_table.id_category`

My .ldf file grows a lot during the `DELETE`.

**Why are my `DELETE` queries slower when I have indexes on my tables?**  I thought they were supposed to run faster.

**UPDATE**

Okay, consensus seems to be indexes will slow down a huge `DELETE` becuase the index has to be updated. Although, I still don't understand why it can't `DELETE` all the rows all at once, and just update the index once at the end.

I was under the impression from some of my reading that indexes would speed up `DELETE` by making searches for fields in the `WHERE` clause faster.

[Odetocode.com says:](http://odetocode.com/Articles/70.aspx)

"Indexes work just as well when searching for a record in DELETE and UPDATE commands as they do for SELECT statements."

But later in the article, it says that too many indexes can hurt performance.

Answers to **bobs** questions:

1. 55 million rows in table
2. 42 million rows being deleted
3. Similar `SELECT` statement would not run (Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown)

I tried the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM big_table
WHERE big_table.id_product IN (
SELECT small_table.id_product FROM small_table
WHERE small_table.id_category = 1)

SELECT * FROM big_table
INNER JOIN small_table
ON small_table.id_product = big_table.id_product
WHERE small_table.id_category = 1
```

Both **failed** after running for **25 min** with this error message from SQL Server 2005:

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

The database server is an older dual core Xeon machine with 7.5 GB ram.  It's my toy test database :) so it's not running anything else.

*Do I need to do something special with my indexes after I `CREATE` them to make them work properly?*

Comment: How many rows are in the table?  How many rows are being deleted?  How long would a similar SELECT statement take to complete?  Knowing how fast the SELECT statement takes might give some insight as to how the indexes affect the DELETE.

Comment: It takes longer because when you perform a delete, the indexes that refer to your table have to be updated as well.

Comment: 55 mil rows, 42 deleted, doesn't complete, see above for more details

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Indexes make lookups faster - like the index at the back of a book.

Operations that change the data (like a DELETE) are slower, as they involve manipulating the indexes. Consider the same index at the back of the book. You have more work to do if you add, remove or change pages because you have to also update the index.

Answer (score 3):

I Agree with Bobs comment above -  if you are deleting large volumes of data from large tables deleting the indices can take a while on top of deleting the data its the cost of doing business though. As it deletes all the data out you are causing reindexing events to happen.

With regards to the logfile growth; if you arent doing anything with your logfiles you could switch to [Simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191164.aspx) logging; but i urge you to read up on the impact that might have on your IT department before you change.

If you need to do the delete in real time; its often a good work around to flag the data as inactive either directly on the table or in another table and exclude that data from queries; then come back later and delete the data when the users aren't staring at an hourglass. There is a second reason for covering this; if you are deleting lots of data out of the table (which is what i am supposing based on your logfile issue) then you will likely want to do an indexdefrag to reorgnaise the index; doing that out of hours is the way to go if you dont like users on the phone !

Answer (score 2):

JohnB is deleting about 75% of the data. I think the following would have been a possible solution and probably one of the faster ones. Instead of deleting the data, create a new table and insert the data that you need to keep. Create the indexes on that new table after inserting the data. Now drop the old table and rename the new one to the same name as the old one.

The above of course assumes that sufficient disk space is available to temporarily store the duplicated data.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to avoid bulk delete (and thereby avoid log file growth)

```
declare @continue bit = 1

-- delete all ids not between starting and ending ids
while @continue = 1
begin

    set @continue = 0

    delete top (10000) u
    from    <tablename> u WITH (READPAST)
    where   <condition>

    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        set @continue = 1 

end
```

Comment: The question seems to be more about why the indexes are slow rather than how to delete a big quantity of entries, but this seems to be useful and I found this question because I need to delete a lot of entries, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try TSQL extension to DELETE syntax and check whether it improves performance:

```
DELETE FROM big_table
FROM big_table AS b
INNER JOIN small_table AS s ON (s.id_product = b.id_product)
WHERE s.id_category  =1
```

Comment: This didn't help at all; it took the exact same time as `delete from big_table where exists (select 1 from small_table where small_table.id_product = big_table.id_product and small_table.id_category = 1)`