# Delete 'WITH INDEX' SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

Normal DELETE :

```
DELETE 
FROM Table
WHERE   column1 =   'some value'
```

DELETE WITH INDEX :

```
DELETE  Table1
FROM    Table1  WITH(INDEX(PK_Table1))
WHERE   column1 =   'some value'
```

I know that when you delete a row from a table it will search for all reference tables, which slows down delete execution.

How does delete using WITH INDEX work?

Comment: You can measure on any sgbd. You can also see the plan the optimizer chooses, which lets you see that the optimizer doesn't need your help here to find the trivial index. Don't clutter your code with a trivial hint.

Comment: It is unlikely - More often than not SQL Server will choose the best execution plan, it is usually edge cases where an index hint is required. You should compare execution plans, and run tests. In summary [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server DELETE is slower with indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453833/sql-server-delete-is-slower-with-indexes)

Comment: Now that you have altered your question the answer is a definite no. If you are experiencing performance issues when deleting due to the referential integrity checks, the only way to resolve this is to put indexes on the foreign key columns that reference table1 PK.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: am using MS SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WITH(INDEX(PK_Table1))` is an index hint; i.e. tells SQL to use a specific index rather than trying to determine the best one.  Generally index hints aren't needed; SQL is very good at knowing what's best; and doesn't take much time working out the best index, since it recalls which index it used the last time it had a similar query.

There are some cases where SQL may get it wrong; for those you could improve performance by adding a hint.  These cases are very rare.  In such cases, test thoroughly, and with data as close to real-world as possible (as what data's in the table will impact how well the query performs under each index

Unless you're seeing a real performance problem & can prove that your hint helps, don't use the hint.

Here's a related post on hints, which summarises the argument well: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/10/index-hints-helpful-or-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

By defining an **alias** you can use an index table hint on delete statement:

```
DELETE X
FROM   Table1 X WITH(INDEX(IX_Table1_Column1))
WHERE  Column1 = 'some value'
```

Without using alias you get an error like that:

```
Msg 1069, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Index hints are only allowed in a FROM or OPTION clause.
```